# The meaning of the episode names in "The Promised Neverland"

Tags: the-promised-neverland

The episodes in *The Promised Neverland* (*Yakusoku no Neverland*) thus far have been:

1. 121045
2. 131045
3. 181045
4. 291045
5. 301045
6. 311045

At first, I didn't give them much thought as they appear to be a number similar to what is tattooed on the children's necks, so I assumed that is what they were, possibly signifying that an episode is about a certain character. However, the number does not appear to match any of the characters. On closer inspection, the current numbers are the same except for the first two numbers that change.

At a quick glance, they appear to be dates... is that what they are? The day on which the episode occurs

> which would imply the story probably takes place in October of the year 2045?

What is the significance of the numbers used for episode names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the episode titles are dates. For example the first episode's title is 121045, which means 12th October, and it corresponds to the date that Conny leaves to "get adopted". You can see the date on a calendar in the first episode:

[image: screenshot from episode 1]

Similarly, the second episode is titled 131045, which is the day after Conny leaves, and so on...

Comment: Although they're also tangentially related to the tattoo numbers, because the tattoos have a pattern to them, somehow related to their age as Ray, Emma's, and Norman's all end in 194.

Comment: @Kai Interesting, I hadn't noticed that either... will take a look and maybe raise another question later.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought it was used to show which student was taken  by these so called "Monsters" Because I thought maybe it was to indicate who was going to die. then I noticed that they started scratching them off,, so I thought maybe it was to show when they were going to escape. There is a scene in episode 7 where Isabella scratches off November 1. The episode is named 011145 for 1/11/2045, in the manga they escape on 15/1/2046.